# Delete branches listed by git branch -a

Tags: git

The command `git branch -a` lists a bunch of branches that are NOT on the repository, and NOT local branches. How can these be deleted?

```
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/cloner
```

For example, `remotes/origin/cloner` used to exist in the repo, but it has since been deleted and I'd like it not to appear when typing `git branch -a`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have remote-tracking branches (such as `origin/cloner` in this case) which are left over after the corresponding branch has been deleted in the remote repository, you can delete all such remote-tracking branches with:

```
git remote prune origin
```

The [documentation for `git remote`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-remote.html) explains this as:

> Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under <name>. These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by <name>, but are still locally available in "remotes/<name>".
>
> With `--dry-run` option, report what branches will be pruned, but do not actually prune them.

Comment: It's worth expanding on this, perhaps just by quoting and linking to the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

To delete a branch which is not needed anymore you can use the following command :

```
git branch -d -r origin/cloner
```

Comment: This needs to be `git branch -d -r origin/cloner`, since `origin/cloner` is a remote-tracking branch.

Answer (score 0):

You  also do

```
git push origin :cloner
```

To remove unwanted remote branches

Comment: In this case, the branch `cloner` has already been deleted from the remote repository, so this will produce an error.  The question is asking how to remove the remote-tracking branch `origin/cloner`, which is left over after someone has deleted `cloner` in `origin`.

Comment: I see. Then, wouldn't a git fetch just refresh the remote branch list?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `main` and `develop` branch and delete all local branch from git repository then this might be helpful.

Delete all local branch *except* **main** and **develop**:

`git branch -a | egrep -v "(^\*|main|develop)" | xargs git branch -d`

Answer (score -5):

It may also happen that the remote repository reference has been deleted from the local clone, but still appears in the output of the 'git branch -a' command.
In any case, you can always suppress any reference simply by deleting the corresponding files:

```
$ rm -f .git/refs/remotes/cloner
$ rm -rf .git/refs/remotes/deprecated_remote
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to directly delete files from under `.git` rather than using porcelain commands to do so.

Comment: Git is quite robust. It is most often very handy to have to edit the .git/config file, for instance to add tracking for a given branch or to change the URL of a remote repository.
By looking directly under the hood, once can understand more easily how Git works, and realise that it is as magic as it appeared the first time.
So, I would not recommend that everybody edits the Git files under the hood, but I would recommend that they at least have a loot at those files. At the mininum, it is very instructive.