# SVN to Git conversion - branches not pushed to Bitbucket

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket

I'm new to Git and having some issues migrating my SVN. I was able to correctly convert to a git repo that looks good on my local machine. When I push it to bitbucket however, I only see the master and none of my branches (which I can see on my local git. )

I see something like.

On my local machine:

```
$git branch -vva 
* master                                                               
  remotes/branch1
  remotes/branch2
```

Bitbucket only shows this master and no branches.

These branches can basically become tags at some point ( mostly just old revisions of the code that are no longer in use.) But I would like them to still exist in the git version.

How can I push what I have locally to bitbucket easily ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firedrill: Recreate central git repository from developers clones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034411/firedrill-recreate-central-git-repository-from-developers-clones)

Comment: Did you use `git push --all` to push your local branches? Otherwise you only push the branch you're currently on.

Comment: If the suggestion from @Dekker doesn't work could you please add the output of `git show-refs` to your question (appropriately redacted for a public forum)?

Comment: Would you mind changing the title of your question to make it easier to find for those that might be having the same problem? I suggest _"SVN to Git conversion - branches not pushed to Bitbucket"_, or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible reasons that you are not seeing the branches on Bitbucket.

1. Your question is a duplicate of [Firedrill: Recreate central git repository from developers clones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034411/firedrill-recreate-central-git-repository-from-developers-clones), as [@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023266/push-git-branches-to-bitbucket/40024271#comment67324787_40023266).
2. You have *remote tracking branches* in your repository that you are trying to push.

If it's the later, you should know that Git only pushes your **local branches** to the remote and not your **remote tracking branches**.

Your *local branches* are the ones that git prints when you run

```
git branch      # show only local branches
```

Your *remote tracking branches* are the ones that git prints when you run

```
git branch -r   # show only remote tracking branches
```

But what you were running was showing you both the *local* and *remote tracking* branches

```
git branch -a   # show both local and remote tracking branches
```

To make a remote tracking branch a local branch you can run

```
git branch <local-branch-name> <remote-branch-name>
```

Or in your specific example

```
git branch branch1 remotes/branch1
```

However, I have a feeling that there's more to your repository than you mentioned because the `remotes/branch1` is not really the correct convention for branch names... The reason I say that is that the `remotes` keyword is special and used in `refs/remotes/` which is the official prefix of all *remote tracking branches*.

Can you please provide us with the output of the `git branch` and `git branch -r` commands (appropriately redacted for a public forum), and let us know which branches you expect Git to push to Bitbucket?

Edit: From @DanielMoss's comment referring to the [Atlassian SVN import process](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-convert/):

> Branches and tags are not imported into the new Git repository as you
>   might expect. You won’t find any of your SVN branches in the git
>   branch output, nor will you find any of your SVN tags in the git tag
>   output. But, if you run git branch -r, you’ll find all of the branches
>   and tags from your SVN repository. **The git svn clone command imports
>   your SVN branches as remote branches and imports your SVN tags as
>   remote branches prefixed with tags/**.

Comment: You're correct I simulated the outpuit of that function. Ultimately my issues was solved via : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-convert/

Comment: I ran the .jar referenced at the bottom of that guide and it restructured my repo into more what I was looking for. I believe your solution was correct however and that I had a heap of remote branches I needed to make local.

Comment: So it seems it was option 2. I too learned something today, I didn't know SVN import did that.